# MT4 Manager API how to get opening positions

Tags: c#, mt4

I would like to get the list of opening positions from MT4 via MT4 Manager API, I am using the ClrWrapper library.
Below is my source code, I tried few methods, but all returned me empty list.

Code 1:

```
var mt = new ClrWrapper("\mtmanapi.dll");
var connect = mt.Connect("0.0.0.0:443");
mt.Login(0, "abcac");
mt.PumpingSwitchEx(PumpingMode.Default);
var na = mt.TradesGet();
var open = mt.TradesGetByLogin(0, "abc");
```

Code 2:

```
var mt = new ClrWrapper("\mtmanapi.dll");
var connect = mt.Connect("0.0.0.0:443");
mt.Login(0, "abcac");
mt.PumpingSwitch((i)=> { });
var na = mt.TradesGet();
var open = mt.TradesGetByLogin(0, "abc");
```

Code 3:

```
var mt = new ClrWrapper("\mtmanapi.dll");
var connect = mt.Connect("0.0.0.0:443");
mt.Login(0, "abcac");
var na = mt.TradesGet();
var open = mt.TradesGetByLogin(0, "abc");
```

Comment: can you please format your code using the toolbar...

Comment: are you still using this mtmanapi.dll?